# GlassMapper Get Default Context V5

Tags: orm, sitecore, glass-mapper

We recently updated to GlassMapper V5 (and also Sitecore 9) and our application is breaking almost everywhere.

I am not able to find enough documentation on this. I see that ISitecoreContext has become obsolete and we are asked to use *IMvcContext*, *IRequestContext* etc., but I don't know how to use them.

This is what I have currently and I am not sure how to get the default Sitecore context. It throws an error saying that

> SitecoreContextFactory doesn't exist

My code:

```
   ILink link = SitecoreContextFactory.Default.GetSitecoreContext().GetItem<ILink>(SitecoreItems.StoreLocatorPage);
```

This is one such example. Can someone point me to the right documentation where I can find all replacement methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation about upgrading to GlassMapper V5 with the replacement methods can be found [here](http://www.glass.lu/mapper/documentation/Upgrade-ToV5).

You are absolutely right, *SitecoreContext* class has been marked as obsolete and from now on you should be using the new context offers:

- **MvcContext** - use it for Controller Renderings; it provides access to DataSourceItem, PageContextItem, RenderingItem and RederingParameteres.
- **RequestContext** - use it when you are outside of a controller and do not have a DataSource item available, i.e. event handler, pipeline processor.

Both contexts use *SitecoreService* for communication with Sitecore.

Answer (score 1):

We created an Extension for the IMvcContext and used that by just adding the namespace and no code change is required in solution